# How to use setReturnsDistinctResults with Magical Record?

Tags: ios, core-data, unique, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I am trying to get unique results on an entity property named "name".
I am using Magical Record with NSFetchedResultsController for that purpose
Things are not working at all, I get all the results but they are not unique results.

My code to make it work is a follow:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"custom == 0"];

    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"name"]];


    _fetchedResultsController = [MyQuestion fetchAllSortedBy:@"name"
                                                   ascending:YES
                                               withPredicate:predicate
                                                     groupBy:nil
                                                    delegate:self];

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I also tried to use the native NSFetchedResultsController method (without Magical Record), but I get the database is corrupt exception, maybe because I am still initialising my data with Magical Record on the app delegate.

Comment: I don't know Magical Record, but your code cannot work, because you set the properties of `_fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest` **before** you initialize `_fetchedResultsController`!

Answer (score 1):

The technique you want to use in this case is to:

1. Create a fetch request with your custom options
2. Let MagicalRecord take over after that

So, look for a category method on nsmanagedobject called MR_requestAllSortedBy:. There are more request helpers than that, but this will put you in the right direction. After you create a fetch request, set your options, like setReturnsDistinctResults. Then, to send it back to the MagicalRecord helper/pipeline, you'll need to make the MR_fetchController:... Method public in your local copy. This method takes a fetch request, and other options, and also handles the error handling, etc.